# Getting 'large' errors that seem too big to be from rounding alone

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, math, rounding

When I use Python, I'm getting some significant rounding errors that seem too large for simply floating point problems. I have the following variables:

```
p = 2.2*10**9
m = 0.510999*10**6
```

I then send it through the following:

```
b = 1/np.sqrt((m/p)**2 + 1) = 0.99999997302479693
```

I then use this value through another equation that should return p:

```
p = (1/np.sqrt(1-b**2)) * m * b = 2200000008.1937...
```

Aforementioned gives a difference in p of 8.19... (error in the 9th decimal place if scientific notation is used), which seems to be way too big to be simply a matter of rounding.

I've tried using `Decimal().sqrt()` with arbitrarily high precision for all the calculations and I get a difference in p of 1.8935..., which is only marginally better.

Is there a better way of getting higher precision?

Comment: A difference of 8 in 2.2x10^9 is a trivial amount of error

Comment: Unfortunately, there are other elements in the code that change the value of p by almost 8,  so 8 becomes non trivial.

Comment: Based on the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/basics.types.html#extended-precision) it looks like you may be at the limit of `numpy` precision.  I tried your code with the `numpy.longdouble` and got the same results you post in your question

Comment: You're going to need to either adapt your algorithm to work with the limits of floating-point precision, or brute-force it by throwing an arbitrary-precision arithmetic library at the problem and eat the time and memory cost.

Comment: Incidentally, if you're going to use `decimal`, make sure you create the `decimal.Decimal` instances from strings instead of floats, and don't mix in any normal floats or NumPy operations.

Comment: *"Is there a better way of getting higher precision?"* [mpmath](http://mpmath.org/)

Comment: I find it hard to believe you were using arbitrary precision for all the calculations if you got that error.  That's exactly what you'd get if you divided m/p in the _default_ precision.  When I do it all in Decimal with 1000 prec, I get an error of Decimal('-9.638874E-984').  But I second WW's mpmath recommendation -- decimal is pretty limited in the number of operations you can use conveniently.

Comment: Even with the default precision, [`decimal.Decimal` gives an error of about 8e-12](http://ideone.com/XbySEc).

Comment: @DSM you are right. I found that I didn't have the Decimal() wrapper around p in the equation and that was limiting my precision. When I added that wrapper, the precision greatly increased. Thank you.

Comment: Error calculation is *hard*. You can't just assume that every calculation being good to within 1 or 2 lsb will give you a *result* that is equally accurate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is the operation

```
sqrt(1+x)
```

that loses you that much precision. Or really the `1+x` part of it. As your `x=(m/p)**2` has the magnitude `1e-6`, you lose about 5-6 digits of the 15-16 valid decimal digits of `x`, so that only 9-10 valid digits remain. And in the reconstruction you see exactly that, (only) the leading 9 digits are correct.